# Не понимаю двоичное счисление в приведенном примере

Tags: java

Объясните пожалуйста смысл приведенной строчки,и в частности почему используется такая итерация "t = t/2" 
[image: Строчка выделенная рыжим]
P. S. По возможности посоветуйте литературу чтобы больше таких глупых вопросов не возникало :)

Comment: Как я понял, это Герберт Шилдт?

Comment: добро пожаловать на stack overflow на русском! текстовую информацию лучше прилагать в виде текста: а) читать легче; б) можно копировать; в) поиск работает. исправить текст вопроса можно, нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса

Comment: Да, совершенно точно,долго думал начать либо со сьера  и бейтс изучаем java либо с шилдта, пришел к выводу что шилдт лучше

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Если кратко, то эта операция сдвигает единичный бит в маске на одну позицию вправо.
Эквивалентно записи:

```
t >> 1
```

Если подробнее, то число 128 в двоичной системе счисления:

```
10000000
```

Если 128 поделить пополам, то получим 64, что в двоичной системе счисления:

```
01000000
```

32 будет соответствовать:

```
00100000
```

И так далее единичный бит будет сдвигаться в самую крайнюю правую позицию.

**Для чего это нужно?**

Дело в том, что в цикле используется побитовое `&`, и на каждой итерации мы последовательно получаем бит из переменной `val`. В результате, если получается положительное число, значит на данной позиции стояла единичка, иначе 0. Если не понимаете, почему это именно так, рекомендую почитать, как работают [побитовые операции](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%91%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B5_%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8#%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B5_%C2%AB%D0%98%C2%BB_(AND))

Comment: Спасибо, ваш ответ мне помог разобраться, но вы не могли бы мне посоветовать что мне почитать чтобы разбираться именно в системах счисления, а то можно сказать что начал джаву изучать с нуля, то бишь без каких либо знаний по информатике

Comment: @ДДД какой-то конкретной литературы посоветовать не могу, но в интернете достаточно ресурсов, на которых раскрывается тема систем счисления (определения, перевод из одной в другую, арифметика и т.д.). Хотел бы заметить, что это общая базовая тема, не привязанная конкретно к языку программирования Java. Я бы вам советовал сейчас развиваться без конкретной привязки к ЯП, а набираться знаний в области информатики в целом. Например, двигаться в сторону структур данных и алгоритмов. Языки программирования рождаются и умирают, а структуры данных и алгоритмы используются десятилетиями.

Comment: Только `t >> 2` это разделить на 4, а пополам это `t >> 1`

Comment: @avp, да, действительно, исправил описку

Answer (score 0):

Потому что у двоичной системы счисления - степень двойки.
Обратите внимание на побитовую операцию &, можно расписать этот цикл как:

```
// 0 1 1 1 1 0 1 1

// 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0   (128)
// &
// 0 1 1 1 1 0 1 1   (123)
// 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0   0

// 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0  (64)
// &
// 0 1 1 1 1 0 1 1   (123)
// 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0   1

// 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0  (32)
// &
// 0 1 1 1 1 0 1 1   (123)
// 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0   1

// 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0  (16)
// &
// 0 1 1 1 1 0 1 1   (123)
// 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 0   1

// 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0  (8)
// &
// 0 1 1 1 1 0 1 1   (123)
// 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0   1

// 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0  (4)
// &
// 0 1 1 1 1 0 1 1   (123)
// 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0   0

// 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0  (2)
// &
// 0 1 1 1 1 0 1 1   (123)
// 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0   1

// 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1  (1)
// &
// 0 1 1 1 1 0 1 1   (123)
// 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1   1
```

Так для перевода обратно надо будет сделать следующее:

```
0 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 

 (0*2^7) + (1*2^6) + (1*2^5) + (1*2^4) + (1*2^3) + (0*2^2) + (1*2^1) + (1*2^0)
  0    +   64    +   32    +   16    +    8    +   0     +   2     +    1     = 123
```